# How to make geom_segment "start over" once a limit has been reached

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data on shift lengths. Right now, I am trying to visualize which shifts overlap. As an example, consider three shifts, a 12 hour shift beginning at 8am and ending at 8pm, an 8 hour shift, beginning at 8am and ending at 4pm, and a final 12 hour shift beginning at 4pm and ending at 4am.

I am trying to create a `geom_segment` graph that essentially plots these three shifts with three segments—one for each shift. The x-axis would be the hour of the day (00:00-23:59).

The difficulty I am having is figuring out how to make the shift beginning at 4pm "start over" once it goes past the 23rd hour. Essentially, I would want a solid line beginning at 4pm (ie 16:00), going on until 11:59pm (ie 23:59), and then starting back over at 12am (00:00) and going until 4am (04:00).

Here is a sample tibble:

```
# Load the necessary packages
library(lubridate)
library(tibble)

# Define shift information as a tibble
shift_info <- tibble(
  shift = c("Shift 1", "Shift 2", "Shift 3"),
  start_time = ymd_hms(c("2023-03-03 08:00:00", "2023-03-03 08:00:00", "2023-03-03 16:00:00")),
  end_time = ymd_hms(c("2023-03-03 20:00:00", "2023-03-03 16:00:00", "2023-03-04 04:00:00"))
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to do some data wrangling you split the shift extending over two days into two parts or observations. Note that this also requires to reset the date, so I dropped the date from the axis label:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

shift_info <- shift_info |>
  filter(day(start_time) < day(end_time)) |>
  mutate(
    start_time = ceiling_date(start_time, "day"),
    across(c(end_time, start_time), ~ .x - days(1))
  ) |>
  bind_rows(shift_info) |>
  mutate(end_time = if_else(
    day(start_time) < day(end_time),
    floor_date(end_time, "day"),
    end_time
  ))

ggplot(shift_info, aes(start_time, shift,
  xend = end_time,
  yend = shift, color = shift
)) +
  geom_segment(linewidth = 3) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H:%M")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)


shift_info$end_time[3] <- shift_info$end_time[3] + days(1)

ggplot(shift_info, aes(x = hour(start_time):hour(end_time), y = shift)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = hour(start_time), xend = hour(end_time), yend = shift), color = "gold", size = 3) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 23)) +
  labs(x = "Hour of the day", y = "") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]